# How can I mock an object passed into a function using Sinon.js?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, sinon

I have a function on an input field that adds a percent sign to the value from the user input. The function looks like the following:

```
addPercentSign: function (oEvent, control) {
  var inputVal = oEvent.getParameters().value;
  var inputNumber = parseFloat(inputVal);

  if (inputNumber) {
    if (inputNumber < 50 || inputNumber > 100) {
      return null;
    } else {
      var finalVal = inputNumber.toFixed(1);
      var finalOutput = finalVal + "%";

      control.learningCurve.setValue(finalOutput);
    };
  }
}
```

Since this function relies on an Event object, how can I 'mock' the parameters (using Sinon.js) to create a unit test for this function?

Since the oEvent object is how we retrieve the user input, I'm not sure what the strategy is to write this specific test? Possibly stubs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you're after with the following:

```
test('adds a percent sign to user input above 50', () => {

  // Create a stubbed input event so we can control the input value
  var inputEvent = {
    getParameters: sinon.stub().returns({ value: '51' })
  }

  // Create a spy so we can observe any calls to `setValue` 
  // and assert the output value is correct
  var setValue = sinon.spy();
  var control = {
    learningCurve: { setValue: setValue }
  }

  // Execute unit-under-test
  addPercentSign(inputEvent, control)

  // Assert `setValue` called with our expected output value.
  assert(setValue.calledWith('51.0%'))

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this solution makes a lot of sense, but the test is not quite passing just yet. I receive an error that says 'control.learningCurve.setValue is not a funciton'.

Comment: Apologies, slight there was a slight error in the `control` stub. Have updated!

Comment: Thanks! I have another question on the same topic if you were interested in taking a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272975/how-can-i-stub-methods-attached-to-the-this-object-using-sinon-js