# How can I stub methods attached to the 'this' object using Sinon.js?

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, mocking, sinon, qunit

I'm attempting to test the 'onInit' function attached below:

```
function (jQuery, Controller, JSONModel) {
        "use strict";

        var controls;

        var mainController = Controller.extend("tool.controller.Main", {

            onInit: function(oEvent) {

                var inputModel = new JSONModel("./model/inputs.json");
                var productsModel = new JSONModel("./model/products.json");

                this.getView().setModel(inputModel, "inputModel");
                this.getView().setModel(productsModel);

                controls = viewControls.main.apply(this);
            },
...
```

**Objective**

For this function in particular, I simply need to test that the 'setModel' and 'main' methods get called.

**The Problem I'm facing**

There are a few dependencies that I need to stub/mock  in order to consider this 'onInit' function properly unit tested. Specifically those dependencies would be would be the following:

- 'this' keyword/object that has a 'getView' method attached to it
- 'JSONModel' object constructor

I'm stuck with understanding how I can mock the aforementioned. Below is what I have tried with my beginner level understanding of Sinon.js:

```
QUnit.test("'onInit' Function Test", function(assert) {

          // Arrange   
         var JSONModel = sinon.stub();  
         var inputModel = sinon.stub();
         var productsModel = sinon.stub();

         //spies- what methods are we asserting get called?
         var setModel = sinon.spy();
         var main = sinon.spy()

         //stubs- what dependencies are we 'faking'
        sinon.stub(this, 'getView').returns({setModel});

         // Act 
         mainController.onInit();

         // Assert 
         assert.ok(setModel.called, "setModel called");
         assert.ok(main.called, "setModel called");


        });
```

I'm pretty sure there is a better approach as this might be completely the wrong strategy. Your suggestions will greatly be appreciated as I learn unit testing in its entirety. Here is the error I get if it helps:

[image]

Comment: In `sinon.stub(this, 'getView')` the value of `this` is not `mainController` hence the stub is failing. If you want to stub `getView` you'll have to stub it on the `mainController` e.g. `sinon.stub(mainController, 'getView')`, however...You probably want to avoid stubbing `getView` (since that belongs to your unit-under-test) and try stubbing/spying on the object returned from `getView` because that is presumably an external object passed into (or created by) `mainController`. (Not sure what framework/libs your using so can't really advise much further on how to achieve that).

Comment: Also, stubbing `JSONModel` won't work because it's not going to affect the value passed into your top-level anonymous function `function (jQuery, Controller, JSONModel) ...`. Those values are most-likely provided by whatever framework you're using or if it's an IIFE then there ;)

Comment: @Kode_12 - were you able to solve your issue?